# Number of $l$-dimensional subspaces of a vector space containing a given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

> What is the number of $l$ dimensional subspaces of $V$ containing a given $k$ dimensional subspace?

Where $F$ is a finite field with $q$ elements and $V$ is an $n$ dimensional vector space over $F$.

Comment: How can a 1-dimensional subspace contain a given $k$-dimensional subspace if $k>1$? Did you mean to ask about the number of 1-dimensional subspaces that a given $k$-dimensional subspace contains?

Comment: No it is not 1 it is L (small)

Comment: In order to make things clearer, I have used $\ell$, which is a script L (by typing `$\ell$`).  You might prefer to change that to $l$ (by typing `$l$`), but I do recommend that you keep the `$`'s there, whatever you choose to do.

Comment: Also, please be aware that askers are generally expected to provide [some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to their question, outside of the question-statement itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ denote our $k$-dimensional space, and let $W$ denote the $l$-dimensional space which contains it.

**Hint:** There is a one-to-one correspondence between the spaces $W$ containing $U$ and the [quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)) $W/U$, each of which is an $l-k$ dimensional subspace of $V/U$.